# Передача данных между формами в Visual Studio C++

Tags: winforms, c++

В проекте две формы. `Form2` вызывается по нажатию кнопки в `Form1` посредством `Form2->ShowDialog();`
(предварительно в `Form1.h` был прописан `#include <Form2.h>`)
Вопрос: Как передать в `Form2` несколько указателей типа `Test ^Name`? `Test` - структура:

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        ref struct Test
        {
            System::String ^test1;
            int test2;
        };
    ...
```

Comment: Ставьте уж таг CLI, или что это там... `System::String ^` - это не C++.

Answer (score 1):

1. Писать на C++ managed код - извращение. Лучше возьмите C#
2. Чтобы обеспечить межмодульное взаимодействие существует несколько способов.

   - Глобальная переменная. Получаете все минусы глобальных объектов.
   - Локальная переменная для класса `Form2`. Инициализировать через конструктор `Form2`.
   - Локальная переменная для класса `Form2`. Инициализировать через отдельную ф-цию. Например, `Form2->Init(blablabla)` или `Form2->setmyinternalvariables(blablablah)`
   - Локальная переменная для класса `Form2` с публичным доступом. Кхм. Вероятно не лучший путь.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в класс Form2 указатель на Test, при создании объекта класса Form2 инициализировать этот указатель через конструктор или через геттер (getter). Описание Test вынести из Form1. Далее Form2 -> ShowDialog.

Comment: Как правильно вынести описание Test? Если я пытаюсь описать структуры вне класса, конструктор начинает ругаться "Either VCProject or VCCodeModel is not ready yet. Please close designer and try again. " Перезапуск не помогает.